# Issue with key and iv on AES 256-CBC

Tags: java, android, python-2.7, cryptography, aes

I get a encrypted base64 string from Python.

The format is AES 256 CBC, but when I try to decrypt using Android it return decrypted string as nil.

## Python

```
# coding=utf-8
import base64
from random import choice
from string import letters

try:
    from Crypto import Random
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
except ImportError:
    import crypto
    import sys

    sys.modules['Crypto'] = crypto
    from crypto.Cipher import AES
    from crypto import Random


class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = 32
        self.key = key

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        _raw = raw
        raw = self._pad(raw)

        print raw, ';'
        print _raw, ';'

        iv = "".join([choice(letters[:26]) for i in xrange(16)])
        print " iv :", iv
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')

    def _pad(self, s):
        a = (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)
        b = chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)
        return s + a * b

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
def encrypt(k, t):
    o = AESCipher(k)
    return o.encrypt(t)


def decrypt(k, t):
    o = AESCipher(k)
    return o.decrypt(t)


def main():
    k = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty"
    s1 = "Hello World!"

    d2 = encrypt(k, s1)

    print " Password :", k
    print "Encrypted :", d2
    print "    Plain :", decrypt(k, d2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Java

Here I use https://github.com/fukata/AES-256-CBC-Example

```
final String aEcodedSting = "aWVnZWphbnBleWJlemdteeAal+cw04QPYRuuIC3J1/zbkZZSCqxGLo/a26ZiieOk";
String decrypted = AESUtil.decrypt(aEcodedSting);
```

When I try to decrypt I got this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vinu.aessamble/com.example.vinu.aessamble.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e06b065:Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:BAD_DECRYPT
```

This is the Python encryption output:

```
Password : qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty
Encrypted : aWVnZWphbnBleWJlemdteeAal+cw04QPYRuuIC3J1/zbkZZSCqxGLo/a26ZiieOk
iv : iegejanpeybezgmy
plainText : ser456&*(
```

Please notify me when anyone can solve this using another library.

Comment: Add code here not as link to github

Comment: @Jens :updated now .. thanks for your response

Comment: Please Show a [mcve] so that we can try it by our own

Comment: Python code is working . but having problem in java code when using that library.

Comment: 1. By "Python code is working", does that mean you can round-trip encrypt and decrypt? 2. Encrypting "Hello World!" with CBC and a prepended IV should result in 32 bytes, the result is 48 bytes. It seems you are not encryption what you think you are. Provide the print output of `iv` and `raw`, the actual data being encrypted. 3. As Jens requests, please provide a MCVE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 problems:

1. Difference between python output and java input
2. Different IV and key
3. Different key creation
4. Padding

---

1) Currently your python code output is a base64 encoding of `iv + encrypted_data`

```
return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
```

But in java you're directly *decrypting* raw data.

You should fix this way

```
// Decode base64
byte[] array = Base64.decode(src);
// Get only encrypted data (removing first 16 byte, namely the IV)
byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 16, array.length);
// Decrypt data
decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
```

2) You must use same IV and key for input and output, so you should copy them from python console output:

```
iv : qbmocwtttkttpqvv
Password : qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty
Encrypted : anZxZHVpaWJpb2FhaWdqaCK0Un7H9J4UlXRizOJ7s8lchAWAPdH4GRf5tLAkCmm6
    Plain : Hello World!
```

and paste in java code:

```
private static final String ENCRYPTION_KEY = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty";
private static final String ENCRYPTION_IV = "qbmocwtttkttpqvv";
```

3) In python you're using the key as string, but in java library it is hashed before being used for decrypting, so you should change your `makeKey()` method:

```
static Key makeKey() {
    try {
        byte[] key = ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
        return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

4) Finally, you don't need to specify a padding in java with `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`, because this way you force `Cipher` to pad automatically.

You can simply use `"AES/CBC/NoPadding"` in your `decrypt()` method, so it should look like this:

```
public static String decrypt(String src) {
    String decrypted = "";
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, makeKey(), makeIv());
        byte[] array = Base64.decode(src);
        byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 16, array.length);
        decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

---

Java output with your base64 and IV:

```
encrypted: aWVnZWphbnBleWJlemdteeAal+cw04QPYRuuIC3J1/zbkZZSCqxGLo/a26ZiieOk
decrypted: ser456&*(
```

---

### Edit:

As suggested by [Artjom B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816580/artjom-b) (thank you), it would be better to read IV directly from ciphertext instead of hardcoding in AESUtil.

Your input consists of the IV in first 16 bytes and encrypted text in last 16 bytes, so you could take advantage of this.

```
public static String decrypt(String src) {
    String decrypted = "";
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        // Decode input
        byte[] array = Base64.decode(src);
        // Read first 16 bytes (IV data)
        byte[] ivData = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 16);
        // Read last 16 bytes (encrypted text)
        byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 16, array.length);
        // Init the cipher with decrypt mode, key, and IV bytes array (no more hardcoded)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, makeKey(), new IvParameterSpec(ivData));
        // Decrypt same old way
        decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

Moreover, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497058/issue-with-key-and-iv-on-aes-256-cbc#comment76007442_44503051)

> Python code uses a 32 byte block size for padding which means that Java will still not be able to decrypt half of all possible ciphertexts. AES block size is 16 bytes and this should be changed in the Python implementation

You could change your Python class as below (`AES.block_size` is equal to 16):

```
class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = AES.block_size
        self.key = key
```

Comment: It would be a good suggestion to customize the Java code to read the IV from the ciphertext instead of hard-coding it. Also, you missed that the Python code uses a 32 byte block size for padding which means that Java will still not be able to decrypt half of all possible ciphertexts. AES block size is 16 bytes and this should be changed in the Python implementation.

Comment: I agree, I didn't change more but it would be better. Currently I'm on mobile so I can't make a good edit. Feel free to edit else I'll do it as soon as possible following your suggestion :)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Edited, Thank you

Comment: @ChristianAscone. This is what i got when using NoPadding . ser456&*( + additional blocks . I can not edit python code . please help

Comment: I tried with data you posted in original answer. Base64 `aWVnZWphbnBleWJlemdteeAal+cw04QPYRuuIC3J1/zbkZZSCqxGLo/a26ZiieOk` and iv `iegejanpeybezgmy`, but what I get is `ser456&*(`. Have you tried with decrypt() method in Edit block?

Comment: @ChristianAscone. I tried it but after ser456&*( got some hexadecimal padding . check the length. How can i remove that?

Comment: Could you please provide `makeKey()` code? Tried with base64 above? How do you init and setup cipher instance?

Comment: @ChristianAscone Can i do encryption using the same makeIv() and makeKey()? And i am using this for encryption  public static String encrypt(String src) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            Log.d("DOODLE", "encrypt: " + cipher);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, makeKey(), makeIv());
            return Base64.encodeBytes(cipher.doFinal(src.getBytes()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } is it a correct way?

Comment: `makeKey()` must be changed (take a look at point 3) because it doesn't make the same key of your python code. `makeIv()` can be the same, but if you're following the code I posted in Edit you'll find out it doesn't require that method because the IV is extracted from ciphertext. Let me know if something is not clear

Comment: @ChristianAscone Am using makeIv() (on point 3) and using your code on edits. But when using NoPadding i got an error :  
 javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:1e06c06a:Cipher functions:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:DATA_NOT_MULTIPLE_OF_BLOCK_LENGTH

Comment: Pay attention. Point 3 is about `makeKey()` (Very important), not `makeIv()`. Code on edits doesn't use `makeIv()`.

Comment: Sorry i mean makeKey() . Can avoid error when using PKCS5Padding but that can't be able to decrypted using this method.

Comment: Very strange. Take a look at [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B40ZAucBgosmTHljMl8zR3ZzcUE). It's the same code I posted above, but maybe you are able to find if there are some differences with your.