# AES-256-CBC Encryption in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

Am using library https://github.com/fukata/AES-256-CBC-Example for Encryption and decryption And with the help of [Issue with key and iv on AES 256-CBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497058/issue-with-key-and-iv-on-aes-256-cbc). Decryption is working properly. 
But in the Case of Encryption this error happens

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vinu.aessamble/com.example.vinu.aessamble.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException:error:1e06c06a:Cipher functions:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:DATA_NOT_MULTIPLE_OF_BLOCK_LENGTH
```

And i am using

```
String encrypted = AESUtil.encrypt("My PlainText to encrypt");
```

In AESUtils

```
public static String encrypt(String src) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, makeKey(), makeIv());
        return Base64.encodeBytes(cipher.doFinal(src.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Using this for PKCS5Padding encryption is working but can't decrypted using the method. When using NoPadding for encryption it shows above error.

```
public static String decrypt(String src) {
        String decrypted = "";
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            byte[] array= Base64.decode(src);
            byte[] ivData=Arrays.copyOfRange(array,0,16);
            byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 16, array.length);
            // Init the cipher with decrypt mode, key, and IV bytes array (no more hardcoded)
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, makeKey(), new IvParameterSpec(ivData));
            // Decrypt same old way
            decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
```

makeIv()

```
static AlgorithmParameterSpec makeIv() {
        try {
            return new IvParameterSpec(sha256digest16(ENCRYPTION_IV));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

makeKey()

```
 static Key makeKey() {
        try {
            byte[] key = ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
            return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Iv and key are

```
private static final String ENCRYPTION_KEY = qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty";
    private static final String ENCRYPTION_IV = "qbmocwtttkttpqvv";
```

Help me to do encryption.

Comment: You're not prepending the IV to the ciphertext in your encrypt method.

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV (hash of a static string is still static), because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: Hi, can you please post your final code as an answer?